# Rating Bar color if changed is different in old versions

Tags: android, ratingbar

Minimum API = 15

Target API = 25

I have tried to change the Rating Bar color using this

```
<!-- Custom Rating Bar Style-->
<style name="RatingBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">#FF9800</item>
</style>
```

This changes the color in the API above 21 successfully but below 21 it shows different color.

Take a look

[Color in API 21 & above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcNxc.png)

[Color in API below 21](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpi0K.png)

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Just simply go to res/values/styles.xml and add the two items namely colorControlNormal and colorControlActivated at your desired choice of color

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@android:color/darker_gray</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">#FF9800</item>
</style>
```